# Must a one-dimensional conservative system with same period in spite of initial condition be a simple harmonic oscillator?

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

All the non-trivial solutions ( i.e. $x(t)\not\equiv 0$ )  of $$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = f(x)$$  has the same period, independent of the initial condition. Without loss of generality, set $$f(0)=0$$Does it imply that $$ f = -kx$$?
If not, what  assumptions should be made to reach this conclusion?

update: What if $f$ is restricted to be an odd smooth (or at least continuous) function, in which case,  we want to determine the continuous diffenrentiable function $F$ such that $$ \int_0^{x_0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{F(x_0)-F(s)}}\mathrm{d}s $$ is a constant, and let $f(x) = - F'(x)$.

Comment: I think you need to stipulate that all *non-trivial* solutions have the same period.  For example, the $x(t) = 0$ solution of $\ddot x = -kx$, $k > 0$, has what some might term *any* period, since $x(t  + T ) = x(t)$ for all $T$.  A "trivial solution" in this context is one for which $\dot x = \ddot x = 0$, i.e., it doesn't *move*.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **no**.

Consider any function $f$
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} -k_1 x \quad (x \le 0) \\ -k_2 x \quad ( x > 0)
\end{cases}
$$
such that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{k_1}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{k_2}} = 2$. Solutions of $x''(t) = f(x(t))$ consist of pieces of trigonometric functions that are easy to find. All such solutions have period $2 \pi$.

Answer (score 0):

#

Summary of previous WRONG attempt, to which comments are related, still work in progress:

First of all, we note that the ODE can be physically derived from a conservation of energy (kinetic and potential) equation such as $$ \frac{1}{2} \Big(\frac{\mathrm{d} x}{\mathrm{d}t} \Big)^2– F(x) = F(x_0)  $$ where $F$ is the primitive of $f$, assuming it exists, ($F = \frac{1}{2} k x^2$ for a linear spring law) and $x_0$ is the maximum amplitude reached by the harmonic oscillator.

This makes it easy to calculate the half-period $T$ as

$$ T (x_0)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \int_0 ^{x_0} \frac{\mathrm{d}s}{\sqrt{F(x_0) – F(s)}}$$

We know that if $F(x) = \frac{1}{2} k x^2$, then $T$ is a constant function.

The question boils then down to, can we find a function $F$, such that $\forall x_0$
$$ T (x_0)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \int_0 ^{x_0} \frac{\mathrm{d}s}{\sqrt{F(x_0) – F(s)}} = 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \int_0 ^{x_0} \frac{\mathrm{d}s}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}k x_0^2 – \frac{1}{2}k s^2 }}
$$
As the equality is supposed to be valid for any $x_0$, it is implied that the integrands are the same
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{F(x_0) – F(x)}} = 
\frac{1 }{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}k(x_0)^2 – \frac{1}{2}k x^2 }} $$
which is not possible if $F (x) \neq {\frac{1}{2}k x^2 }$

#

Comment: I don't think the claim "As the equality is supposed to be valid for any x0, it is implied that the integrands are the same" right, since the integrands are functions of x0. Actually I had found the expression of period T as an integral before I asked this question, but to find such function satisfying the condition given by the integral is still very hard, given that it's a improper integral, which makes it hard to find its derivative with respect to x0.

Comment: You are right, that bit is well sloppy. Let me improve it.

Comment: I fofund a counterexample, valid also for sammetric wells,

Comment: Nice: you have shown that a Hamiltonian system with constant period is harmonic. The other answer does not contradict this because it cannot be Hamiltonian: that $f$ lacks the intermediate value property so it is not the derivative of any differentiable function.

Comment: Speaking about previous attempt, can you differentiate the integral with respect to $x_0$, assuming that $f(x)$ is at least smooth? This might give a nice condition and it also bypasses all counter-examples that have been provided.

Comment: @Evgeny, I was just trying to do that. I am though incurring in a problem while using Leibniz's rule, as the term $\frac{1}{\sqrt{F(x_0) - F(x_0)}} $ pops up. Working on it.

Comment: @Ian, did I? not so sure I understand your comment...

Comment: Your assumption that the force is a negative gradient of some energy amounts to assuming that the system is Hamiltonian.

Comment: @Ian, I am afraid the assumption you mention is regretfully part of a faulty argument, as highlighted in my answer.

Comment: Oh, I see. I wonder where the error in that argument is then.

Comment: I don't think it is a valid counter-example, since the equation of motion depends on the amplitude $A$.

Comment: @Ian All equations of form $\ddot{x} = f(x), \; x\in \mathbb{R}$ are Hamiltonian: if $q$ is a generalized coordinate and $p$ is a generalized impulse, then the Hamiltonian equals $\frac{p^2}{2} - F(q)$, where $F'(q) = f(q)$.

Comment: @Evgeny That assumes that $f$ is the derivative of something. Not every function is the derivative of something. In particular, I think things become subtle if $f(x)=\begin{cases} -1 & x>0 \\ 1 & x<0 \end{cases}$.

Comment: @Ian Yeah, you are right, but at first place you need to fix the definition of solution for ODEs with such RHS :) And while it can be fixed, let's speak about easier case now? It seems that Hans Engler already showed that even if $f$ is only continuous there is a counter-example. What if $f$ is $C^1$ or analytic?

Comment: You can find a thorough discussion of the relation between $f$ and the periods of solutions in R. Schaaf's book, Global Solution Branches of Two Point Boundary Value Problems, Springer LN Math 1458.